# Silverlight tabcontrol, how to Keep the current selected tab selected

Tags: silverlight, tabcontrol

I have a tabcontrol which i put inside a dataform that is bound to a collection. if I am on page 1 of the dataform and i select tab 2 of the tabcontrol, when i navigate to page 2 of the dataform the tabcontrol default the selected tab to the first tab. I am using MVVM. So, my question is how do i keep whatever tab was selected to stay selected when I am paging thru the dataform records.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear to what exactly is your tabcontrol selected tab bound. 
if its bound to a some value on object from collection that you are paging through its quite obvious it wont be saved, because it would mean whenever you change tab index you should update entire collection to same index, so when you tab to next item it has same tabindex as previous item had.

You can do this exactly I guess. or post more code so we can find a better solution.

Comment: Hi! here is the scenario: I have an IEnumerable<CustomerDataSource> , so the CustomerDatasource has the following members: CustomerInfo, collection of orders,collection of payments and collection of debts. so each CustomerDatasource is a page on the datafrom and tabs on the dataform are bound to the collections inside CustomerDatasource. So, if I am on page 1 of the dataform and click the second tab which is payments but then when i click next in the dataform toolbar, that's when it default the selected tab to the first one.